# Using 2 public/private key pairs at the "same" time

Tags: ssh, rsa, public-key-encryption

So I have 2 public/private key pairs (id_rsa and id_rsa.pub - one of them is sitting in a "key_backup" folder I made currently), one for GitHub and one for passwordless SSH'ing into a cluster. I looked around Google and could only find guides on how to use two public keys at the same time.. does the same hold for private keys?

How can I maintain authentication w/ GitHub while also being able to maintain passwordless login with my cluster?

Thanks!
-kstruct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use multiple private keys at the same time by making sure that your ssh key agent knows about both keys: `ssh-add id_rsa1 id_rsa2` on Mac OS or Linux, or add both to `Pageant` on Windows.

The other option would be to create separate `Host` entries in [`~/.ssh/config`](http://linux.die.net/man/5/ssh_config) that points each of your two keys at their intended uses.